# rspec Testing of Canadian postal codes with regex, and what other good tests for rspec for CRUD operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am doing some rspec testing for a Canadian postal code. It should pass the test if it follows the regex format. Below is my code

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Postal, type: :model do
  context 'validation tests' do

       it 'should match regex form' do
      postal=(Postal.new(postalcode: 'V5A1S6'))
      expect((postal.postalcode).to match(/\A^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$\z/))

    end
  end
end
```

However, I am getting this failure message.

```
  1) Postal validation tests should match formatting
     Failure/Error: expect((postal.postalcode).to match(/\A^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$\z/))

     ArgumentError:
       bad value for range
     # ./spec/models/postal_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
```

What should I do to get it to pass the regex validation? i'm not sure which part of the code is wrong, or if there is a better solution to test for regex in rspec.

Because in my model validation I have this, and the regex works fine.

```
  validates :postalcode, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6, maximum: 6},  format: { with: /\A^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$\z/}
```

Also I was curious. What other good rspec tests would be meaningful when testing a Canadian postal code, or any other postal codes. All I know of so far is testing the character limits and the regex format.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are got the Regex working, here how you should check the validation in Rspec

```rb
RSpec.describe Postal, type: :model do
  context 'canadian postal code' do
    let(:postal) { Postal.new(postalcode: 'V5A1S6') } # ideally should use factory like FactoryGirl

    it 'record is valid' do
      expect(postal).to be_valid

      # same as above but more explicit
      expect(postal.valid?).to be_truthy

      # even more explicit
      expect(postal.valid?).to eq true
    end
  end

  context 'invalid postal code' do
    let(:postal) { Postal.new(postalcode: '382481') } # ideally should use factory like FactoryGirl

    it 'record is invalid' do
      expect(postal).to be_invalid

      # same as above but more explicit
      expect(postal.valid?).to be_falsey
      expect(postal.invalid?).to be_truthy

      # even more explicit
      expect(postal.valid?).to eq false
      expect(postal.invalid?).to eq true
    end
  end
end
```

I strongly recommend to read following refs.

Ref:

1. [valid? and invalid?](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#valid-questionmark-and-invalid-questionmark)
2. [RSpec: Predicate Matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers)

Comment: Thanks for these Suggestions. But I still wasn't able to get the regex working. I'm still getting a fail error of  


```1) Postal validation tests should match formatting
     Failure/Error: expect((postal.postalcode).to match(/\A^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$\z/))

     ArgumentError:
       bad value for range
     # ./spec/models/postal_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
```

Comment: Your approch is wrong. I have given you how it should be tested with detailed spec. I mentioned I assume that your regex is correct and set correctly in validation rule in model.